How to use Visual Studio Git feature with C++ CMake project
I am working in a project that uses CMake to generate a solution file for Visual Studio. As a result, in one directory I have all my source files and in the other directory there is my build with .sln file.
How can I attach Visual Studio Git to such a project in a single solution?
Note: When I chose git > local repositories in menu I am able to open the code of my project and use git feature. The problem is, that in such a way a new project is being open (I can't intrude changes and complile them in a single Visual Studio instance)

Use a build directory inside the git directory.

Thank you, this solution works. However, I would like to keep builds in the totally different directory

Step 1: Go to Git > Settings > Git Global Settings. 
Step 2: Set option: Close open solutions not under Git when opening a repository to NO.
Now you are able to press: Git > Local Repositories and open your Git information inside your instance of Visual Studio.
